# Wake on Lan Only Working Briefly After Shutdown

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan

Trying to setup Wake on Lan on my desktop, but it seems to only work briefly after I shut it down, then stops working. I have ErP Ready setting disabled (S4 and S5 if I remember right). I have the Power On by PCI-E Enabled which is the wake-on-lan. At first I thought it was my MacBook that was not sending the magic packet since it worked from my Android phone, but realized that it only worked briefly after shutdown. I do not believe it is anything to do with the power state as the NIC Ports stay lit after shutdown, and not just briefly. My motherboard has 2 NICs built in, and I have both connected to an un-managed switch. Home network is running off a Unifi USG with a rpi4 as the controller.

Comment: Check the link LEDs for the Ethernet connections on the switch, are they lit when you shutdown the computer? If not then there is no Ethernet connection and thus no magic packet can be transmitted. Most likely WoL is not active in the used Mainboard for the off state. Try different states like Suspend to Disk or to RAM.

Comment: @Robert I looked at the switch and did see a solid green light if I remember correctly. How would I change the states? In the BIOS? I tried turning on the fast startup or whatever in the power settings in windows, but I couldn't even shut down the computer then, it was acting more like I was signing out of Windows.